Django deploy on Heroku causes causes too many connections error
I have a well-established Django app running on Heroku. It has a Heroku Postgres Standard 0 plan. My latest build upgraded the app to Python 3.12 and Django 4.0, as well as a few dependencies, specifically:

redis>=4.0.0
APScheduler==3.10.4
mozilla-django-oidc==4.0.1
channels-redis==4.2.0
channels==4.0.0
daphne>=4.0.0

In addition, the channels upgrade broke part of my app which uses channels and I couldn't get the SSL None to work so I amended CHANNEL_LAYERS to:
    CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
            "CONFIG": {
                'hosts': [f"{REDIS_URL}?ssl_cert_reqs=none"]
            },
        },
    }

Other than the above, there were no changes to any source code. I tested everything locally and again on my test Heroku Staging server and all was fine. When I deployed to my Heroku Production server my site ground to a halt with the following error:

app/heroku-postgres source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_DB addon=postgresql-db
sample#num_connections_over_limit=90 message=Database connections over
limit. Please upgrade your database plan.

In the end my only solution was to roll back to the previously deplyed version.
I inspected the number of connections to the Postgres DB and found:

In the original working deploy the number of connections would typically sit anywhere between 20 and 24
As soon as this new version was deployed the number of connections rocketed to 210
When I rolled back to my previously deployed version again,the number of connections dropped back down to 20

Not sure if it's relevant here, but my Procfile is:
release: python manage.py migrate
web: daphne achieve.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker channel_layer -v2
clock: python clock.py
worker: celery -A config.celery:app worker --concurrency=2 --loglevel=info

My understanding is that my Heroku Postgres Standard 0 plan allows for 120 connections, so my normal number of around 20ish should be fine. What I need to understand is what might have caused the sudden spike in connections on this most recent deployment?

Side note: You've declared two different processes with the name worker. Pretty sure the first gets overridden by the second.
